# Selective file processing based on matching name string in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a directory A with files named as as ddmmyyyy-ddmmyyyy (both ddmmyyyy represent different dates). There is another directory B that contains files formatted as ddmmyyyy (single date),....  I would like to execute the following code on  files in A to that of B by looking for matching file names. The number of files in A is 28 and  B is 8.

```
parfor ii=1:length(B)-1
    for jj=ii+1:length(B)

       Img1 = abs(ddmmyyyy{ii});

       Img2 = abs(ddmmyyyy{jj}).*exp(1i*angle(ddmmyyyy-ddmmyyyy{ii}{jj}));

       C = Img1.*conj(Img2);

     end
end
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What does your code have to do with your question?

Comment: I don't know how to match the right files in folder B by checking the first and second date of the files in A.

Comment: Also the index "ddmmyyyy-ddmmyyyy{ii}{jj})" in the code is not correct

Answer (score 0):

use `dir`, `fileparts`, and `strtok`:

```
filelistA = dir(dirA);
filelistA(1:2) = [];
filelistA([filelistA(:).isdir]) = [];
[~,fileNamesA,~] = cellfun(@fileparts,{filelistA(:).name},'UniformOutput',false);
[date1A, date2A] = strtok(fileNamesA,'-');
date2A = cellfun(@(x) x(2:end),date2A,'UniformOutput',false);

filelistB = dir(dirB);
filelistB(1:2) = [];
filelistB([filelistB(:).isdir]) = [];
[~,date1B,~] = cellfun(@fileparts,{filelistB(:).name},'UniformOutput',false);
```